# What's the right way to overload the copy assignment operator of an all-const type?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Suppose I have such a struct:

```
struct Foo
{
  const int bar;
  const char baz;

  Foo& operator=(const Foo& other)
  {
    memcpy(this,&other,sizeof(Foo)); //How am I supposed to write this decently?
    return *this;
  }
}
```

I want all fields of Foo to be final, and I want the variables of type Foo to behave just like other primitive value types. Say, int, surely we can write stuff like this:

```
 int i = 0;
 i = 42;

 Foo foo = {007,'B'}
 foo = {42,'X'}
```

Yet for my poor Foo type, do I have to resort to means like memcpy to work around the type safety check? I know I could drop the const modifiers, mark the fields private and add some getters, but that's not the point. I just wanna know if there is a decent way to write the content of the = operator.

Thanks in advance!

~~~~~

Check out the following examples:

```
//If the = op is not implemented, this won't compile
Foo stat;
for(int i=0;i!=100;++i)
{
  stat = func(i);
  if(stat.bar == 0)...
}

//But weird thing is, if I declare the 'stat' inside the for block, it works just fine with gcc
for(int i=0;i!=100;++i)
{
  Foo stat = func(i); 
  //printf("%p\n",&stat); => same variable same address!!
  if(stat.bar == 0)...
}
```

Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: This makes no sense (and that's why you can't make it work). You want const an "all-const" type *that is mutable*? Make up your mind. And no, not even `memcpy` can do that. The end result is undefined behaviour. Get ready to see the compiler doing things you didn't ask it to.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Why couldn't I use memcpy? If it has a definite size and a definite address, why couldn't I write stuff into the mem chuck occupied by it?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Because the members are `const`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no pretty way, and I agree with other answers that you should reconsider the design.

But if you still think it's the least evil for your problem, a couple more options:

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo& other)
{
    const_cast<int&>(bar) = other.bar;
    const_cast<char&>(baz) = other.baz;
    return *this;
}
```

Or

```
#include <memory>

// Foo must never be used as a base class!
// If your compiler supports the c++11 final feature:
struct Foo final
{ /*...*/ };

Foo& operator=(const Foo& other)
{
    if (this != &other) {
        this->~Foo();
        new(this) Foo(other);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: The second one leads to undefined behavior if the actual object has a type that is derived from `Foo`. Don't ever do this! It was a serious mistake for the standard to include this code in its discussion of object lifetime, because it gives people the impression that this is something that's actually useful.

Comment: @aschepler The second solution looks very cool, no cast, no manual memory manipulation, I just like it. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: The first one leads to undefined behaviour in all cases.

Comment: The second also leads to undefined behaviour if the constructor throws. Both options are dangerous. If you need to modify something, don't declare it `const` in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, copy assignment simply makes no sense for an all-`const` type. Don’t implement it.

*Do* use all-`const` types where it makes sense but be aware that this type will *not* behave like `int` because `int` in C++ simply isn’t `const` unless you declare it so.

Comment: Or make the object at the use-site `const`.

Comment: @Xeo Yes – but only if it makes sense to have either `const` or non-`const` objects in the first place. It’s entirely conceivable that objects of a given type never change.

Answer (score 3):

The *decent* way to write it in this case is:

```
Chunk& operator=(const Foo& other) = delete;
```

(or as `private` pre-C++11)

If all your members are `const`, why on earth would you want to change them?

Comment: Decent perhaps, but unnecessary. It's implicitly deleted by the presence of `const` members.